# Google map fragment in another fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I have a Fragment that gets displayed in a tab layout.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        ...
```

However I run into problems when onCreateView gets called again, the inflate method fails because there is already a MapFragment.

I am not sure what the right answer is here as I feel like this is a bug in android.  I.E. I did not create the SupportMapFragment programmatically so I don't feel like I should have to destroy it programatically.

I have seen 'solutions' that say you need to destroy it:

```
public void onDestroy() {
       try {
            Fragment fragment = (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment));  
            FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.remove(fragment);
            ft.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

However if I do that I get:

```
> 04-07 13:59:00.801: W/System.err(20067):
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
> onSaveInstanceState 04-07 13:59:00.801: W/System.err(20067):  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1343)
> 04-07 13:59:00.801: W/System.err(20067):  at
> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1361)
> 04-07 13:59:00.801: W/System.err(20067):  at
> android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
```

Here is my fragment XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        map:uiCompass="false"
        map:uiRotateGestures="false"
        map:uiTiltGestures="false"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If Android inflated the SupportMapFragment should it not destroy that fragment as well.  If not how am I supposed to destroy the SupportMapFragment 'correctly' such that another call to onCreateView does not fail, but also such that I do not get an exception in onDestroyView().

Answer (score -1):

I tried using the supportMapFragment or the MapFragment with different types of fragments and it always gave me a hard time so the only solution that worked fine for me is implementing it manually which is really a few lines of code.

Here is the MapActivity

```
public class Map extends  SherlockFragment implements OnMapClickListener {

    public static GoogleMap googleMap;
private MapView mMapView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);   
     mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initilizeMap();

    }



    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */

    private void initilizeMap() {
        googleMap = null;
            googleMap = ((MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview)).getMap();

            if (googleMap != null) {
              googleMap.setMapType(googleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
              googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
              googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                googleMap.setLocationSource(new CurrentLocationProvider(this));  

            }



    }



      @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mMapView.onResume();
            Log.e("onResume","onResume");

        }


        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mMapView.onPause();
            Log.e("onPause","onPause");

        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if(mMapView!=null){
            mMapView.onDestroy();
            Log.e("map view not null !!","it is not null");

            }else{
                Log.e("map view null!!","it is null");
            }
            super.onDestroy();

        }
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latng) {

    }



}
```

CurrentLocationProvider:

```
public class CurrentLocationProvider implements LocationSource, LocationListener
{
    private OnLocationChangedListener listener;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    public CurrentLocationProvider(Context context)
    {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public void activate(OnLocationChangedListener listener)
    {
        this.listener = listener;
        LocationProvider gpsProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(gpsProvider != null)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(gpsProvider.getName(), 0, 10, this);
        }

        LocationProvider networkProvider = locationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);;
        if(networkProvider != null) {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 60 * 5, 0, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deactivate()
    {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        if(listener != null)
        {
            listener.onLocationChanged(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.75" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is using the old MapView, its not using MapFragment.